# How to calculate the row of the table using javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

This is my page and i have to calculate the 4th row of the table.This table is that i am fetching from the table withing particular date.
The fourth row is empty that i have to feed and update into the table.
I doing calculation in that table should add the rows and show in below.
But it shows NAN.

[image]

My Code:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.ramt').on('change input',function() {
                     var tot = 0;

                       var sub = 0;
                    $('#tb3 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

                        var pamt = $(this).find('.ramt').val();

        tot += parseFloat(pamt);
                    });
$('#rtotal').val(tot);


            });
        });
        </script>
```

this is my table code :

```
 <?php
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($result2);exit();
    if(!empty($query)){
        foreach($query as $key => $row){ // added $key as index
        ?>
            <tr >
                <td ><input style="width:50px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs Sno" name="Sno[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Sno" value="<?=$row['loan_no'];?>"></td>

                <td> <input style="width:180px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="name[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Amount" value="<?=$row['pname'];?>"></td>

                <td ><input style="width:50px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs amt" name="Amount[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Bankname" value="<?=$row['collection_amt'];?>"></td>
                <?php $total_sum=0; ?>  
                <?php if($row['receive_amt'] != 0)
                    $total_sum = $row['receive_amt'];
                        else{
                        $total_sum = "";
                    } ; ?>

                <td ><input style="width:50px" type="text" class="form-control input-xs ramt" name="ramt[<?php echo $key ?>]" id="Chqamt" value="<?php echo"$total_sum"?>" autofocus></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
    }?> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: Where is this? `#tb3`

Comment: that is table id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just iterate over the ramt inputs directly?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.ramt').on('change input',function() {
           var tot = 0;
           $('.ramt').each(function() {
              let val = $(this).val();
              if(val !== '') {
                tot += parseInt(val);
              }
           });
         $('#rtotal').val(tot);
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: try again - i think the issue is based around the inputs that have no number - so I altered the code to only add the values that are present.

Comment: excellent - happy to help. Thanks for accepting my solution. Happy coding :)

Comment: i have another doubt

Comment: whats  up? related to this or another issue?

Comment: related to this only

Comment: sorry - tried to move this a chat - but cannot. Whats the tissue?

Comment: i entered into chat